# C# Hashtable accessing value of type object

Tags: c#, hash, types, casting, runtime

I have a hashtable with a key value pair of 
`(Int, new Timespan())` and I am trying to modify the value 
via

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
table.Add(123, new TimeSpan());
...
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime total = date.Add(table[getInt()]);
```

however it will only return a TimeSpan object at runtime and won't compile so I tried

```
 DateTime total = date.Add(Convert.ChangeType(table[getInt()], typeof(TimeSpan)));
```

and that also did not work, any ideas about accessing objects in hashtables?

Comment: You need a cast.  However, don't do that.  Instead, use generics (`Dictionary<K, V>`)

Comment: Use Convert to create a *new* object of a *differen* type, use [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) to change the type of an *expression* (the object will be the same, unless it's really a type conversion), such as an Object->TimeSpan - and of course that will be a run-time error if the expression does not really represent a TimeSpan ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should be using a generic [`Dictionary<K, V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your `table` variable would then become:

```
var table = new Dictionary<int, TimeSpan>();
```

You then wouldn't need to cast:

```
DateTime total = date.Add(table[getInt()]);
```

In your case where you are using a `Hashtable` you simply need to cast the value coming back:

```
DateTime total = date.Add((TimeSpan)table[getInt()]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the double answer, what is the advantage to using generics in this situation?

Comment: @bischoffingston Some [Type Safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) over this task can be guaranteed at compile-time. If you accidentally put a string (instead of a TimeSpan) into the Hashtable then the cast would fail at run-time with an [InvalidCastException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx). Ick! (But using the generic Dictionary prevents such a mistake - both on insert and retrieval.)

Comment: @bischoffingston in addition to type safety, there's another advantage: instead of typing `date.Add((TimeSpan)table[getInt()])`, you can type 10 fewer characters: `date.Add(table[getInt()])`.  More usefully, the hashtable requires boxing and unboxing the timespan, since it is a value type.  This has a small performance penalty.  With the generic dictionary, there is no boxing.